# Adding common factors in C

Tags: c, function, recursion, addition

I'm just trying to add all common factors of 3 and 5, stopping at a sum of 1000. I keep getting an expected expression on line 15:18. Is there anyone that can find any new errors or help? It would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/*Multiples of 3 and 5
If we list all natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6
and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.*/



int cd_function(int n, int sum)
{

    if(sum >= 1000)
        return 0;

    if(n%3 == 0 || n%5 == 0)
            sum + return cd_function(n, sum);
}


int main(void)
{
    int i, iter, sum = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < cd_function(iter, sum); i++)
        sum++;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You pass an uninitialized `iter` variable to `cd_function()`.

Comment: `sum + return ...` is not what you expect

Comment: Please re-read the problem statement. You do not stop when the sum reaches 1000.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

Most people will add a space here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

.

```
int cd_function(int n, int sum)
{

    if(sum >= 1000)
        return 0;

    if(n%3 == 0 || n%5 == 0)
            sum + return cd_function(n, sum);
}
```

There is two ways, to have this functions add n to sum: Either by passing sum as pointer (reference), this would be done this way:

```
void cd_function(int n, int * sum) {
    // if (*sum >= 1000) - no need to test this here
    if (!n%3 || !n%5) {
        *sum += stuff;
    }
}
```

or by having the function return the new sum:

```
int cd_function(int n, int sum) {
    // if (sum >= 1000) - no need to test this here
    if (!n%3 || !n%5) {
        return sum + stuff;
    } else {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Now, `sum + return cd_function(n, sum);` is wrong, YSC already told so in his comment. So you should either use `*sum += n;` or `return sum + n;` (i.e. replace `stuff` by `n` above).

```
int main(void)
{
    int i, iter, sum = 0;
```

Since you don't need `iter`, get rid of it:

```
    int i, sum = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < cd_function(iter, sum); i++)
        sum++;
```

a. If you want to sum some[tm] `i`s, then you shouldn't increment `sum` in each iteration.

```
    for (i = 0; i < cd_function(iter, sum); i++)
        ;
```

b. Then you should get a proper exit condition. You wanted to sum everything until you reach a sum >= 1000, so write that in the condition:

```
    for (i = 0; sum < 1000; i++)
        /* ??? i < cd_function(iter, sum) */;
```

c. Depending on the implementation of cd_function you choose from above, you would now either call

```
        cd_function(i, &sum);
```

or

```
        sum = cd_function(i, sum);
```

d. And finally, you should add curly brackets, even there is only one statement:

```
    for (i = 0; sum < 1000; i++) {
        // option 1
        cd_function(i, &sum);
        // option 2
        sum = cd_function(i, sum);
    }
```

rest is fine:

```
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @CarsonGedeus, please don't say "thank you" in a comment, instead accept answers, that's the Stack overflow way of saying thank you ;)